# How to do toes without creating more vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, outliner

I'm stuck with how to do the toes of the character without adding vertices nor using texture paint.

These are the feet I have, with 10 vertices at the end to connect it with the legs once finished.
[image]

I thought a way to do the lines for the toes while adding vertices (although I don't want to add more, and the topology looks awful).
[image]

But even with that option, the lines are only seen from the side, if I look the feet from the front, their toes aren't marked.
[image]
[image]

Any way to do toes like in the reference images without breaking the 10 vertices topology nor texture paint?

I tried with normal maps as a comment said, but it is barely seen with the toon shader. First image is the default shader, second one the toon shader.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to use a decal?

Comment: @AllenSimpson I want to use a toon shader, and from the tutorials I have seen about decals, all of them connect the image texture to the "default" shader, so I don't know if it will work with the toon shader, also I don't want to use texture paint because I have to wait until finishing the body to paint it and know if the proportions or shape are okay

Comment: maybe a bump (or normal) map?

Comment: @moonboots I tried with normal normal maps and it doesn't work either :/ I edited the post with the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it needs to be modeled, you can do it with this kind of topology, not sure what it will give with the toon shader though:

[image]

[image]